# Ubuntu 20 & 22: The http URLs in the files under /etc/apt/sources.list.d need to be replaced by https

Tags: apt

Ubuntu 20 & 22:
The apt repo files under /etc/apt/sources.list.d have the below http URLs, but we have a requirement wherein we need to use only the **https URLs**.

http://us-west1.gce.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu

http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu

Can you please let me know what are the equivalent https URLs for the above ones?

Thank you,
Ramakrishna Battula.

Comment: [This](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archivemirrors) might be useful for you.

Comment: Please check your Ubuntu product/release; as 20 & 22 do not not use *deb* packages, they are both *snap* only releases which the *year* format highlights. Ubuntu's *year.month* products use sources like you appear to be being (eg. 20.04, 22.04, 22.10) being able to use *deb*, *snap* packages are more. eg. Ubuntu Core 22 is the *snap* only *flavor* of Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Server.